# How to Add a Input.Boolean to an Array function?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

```
prd = int(10)
ppsrc = string('High/Low')
maxnumpp = int(20)
ChannelW = int(10)
maxnumsr = int(5)
min_strength = int(2)
labelloc = int(20)
linestyle = string('Dashed')
linewidth = int(2)
resistancecolor = color.red
supportcolor = color.lime
showpp = (false)
tplevels = input.bool(false, "Automatic S/R Levels")

float src1 = ppsrc == 'High/Low' ? high : math.max(close, open)
float src2 = ppsrc == 'High/Low' ? low : math.min(close, open)
float ph = ta.pivothigh(src1, prd, prd)
float pl = ta.pivotlow(src2, prd, prd)


Lstyle = linestyle == 'Dashed' ? line.style_solid : linestyle == 'Solid' ? line.style_solid : line.style_solid

//calculate maximum S/R channel zone width
prdhighest = ta.highest(300)
prdlowest = ta.lowest(300)
cwidth = (prdhighest - prdlowest) * ChannelW / 100

var pivotvals = array.new_float(0)

if ph or pl
    array.unshift(pivotvals, ph ? ph : pl)
    if array.size(pivotvals) > maxnumpp  // limit the array size
        array.pop(pivotvals)

get_sr_vals(ind) =>
    float lo = array.get(pivotvals, ind)
    float hi = lo
    int numpp = 0
    for y = 0 to array.size(pivotvals) - 1 by 1
        float cpp = array.get(pivotvals, y)
        float wdth = cpp <= lo ? hi - cpp : cpp - lo
        if wdth <= cwidth  // fits the max channel width?
            if cpp <= hi
                lo := math.min(lo, cpp)
            else
                hi := math.max(hi, cpp)

            numpp += 1
            numpp
    [hi, lo, numpp]

var sr_up_level = array.new_float(0)
var sr_dn_level = array.new_float(0)
sr_strength = array.new_float(0)

find_loc(strength) =>
    ret = array.size(sr_strength)
    for i = ret > 0 ? array.size(sr_strength) - 1 : na to 0 by 1
        if strength <= array.get(sr_strength, i)
            break
        ret := i
        ret
    ret

check_sr(hi, lo, strength) =>
    ret = true
    for i = 0 to array.size(sr_up_level) > 0 ? array.size(sr_up_level) - 1 : na by 1
        //included?
        if array.get(sr_up_level, i) >= lo and array.get(sr_up_level, i) <= hi or array.get(sr_dn_level, i) >= lo and array.get(sr_dn_level, i) <= hi
            if strength >= array.get(sr_strength, i)
                array.remove(sr_strength, i)
                array.remove(sr_up_level, i)
                array.remove(sr_dn_level, i)
                ret
            else
                ret := false
                ret
            break
    ret

var sr_lines = array.new_line(11, na)
var sr_labels = array.new_label(11, na)

for x = 1 to 10 by 1
    rate = 100 * (label.get_y(array.get(sr_labels, x)) - close) / close
    label.set_text(array.get(sr_labels, x), text=str.tostring(label.get_y(array.get(sr_labels, x))) + '(' + str.tostring(rate, '#.##') + '%)')
    label.set_x(array.get(sr_labels, x), x=bar_index + labelloc)
    label.set_color(array.get(sr_labels, x), color=label.get_y(array.get(sr_labels, x)) >= close ? color.red : color.lime)
    label.set_textcolor(array.get(sr_labels, x), textcolor=label.get_y(array.get(sr_labels, x)) >= close ? color.white : color.black)
    label.set_style(array.get(sr_labels, x), style=label.get_y(array.get(sr_labels, x)) >= close ? label.style_label_down : label.style_label_up)
    line.set_color(array.get(sr_lines, x), color=line.get_y1(array.get(sr_lines, x)) >= close ? resistancecolor : supportcolor)

if ph or pl
    //because of new calculation, remove old S/R levels
    array.clear(sr_up_level)
    array.clear(sr_dn_level)
    array.clear(sr_strength)
    //find S/R zones
    for x = 0 to array.size(pivotvals) - 1 by 1
        [hi, lo, strength] = get_sr_vals(x)
        if check_sr(hi, lo, strength)
            loc = find_loc(strength)
            // if strength is in first maxnumsr sr then insert it to the arrays 
            if loc < maxnumsr and strength >= min_strength
                array.insert(sr_strength, loc, strength)
                array.insert(sr_up_level, loc, hi)
                array.insert(sr_dn_level, loc, lo)
                // keep size of the arrays = 5
                if array.size(sr_strength) > maxnumsr
                    array.pop(sr_strength)
                    array.pop(sr_up_level)
                    array.pop(sr_dn_level)

    for x = 1 to 10 by 1
        line.delete(array.get(sr_lines, x))
        label.delete(array.get(sr_labels, x))

    for x = 0 to array.size(sr_up_level) > 0 ? array.size(sr_up_level) - 1 : na by 1
        float mid = math.round_to_mintick((array.get(sr_up_level, x) + array.get(sr_dn_level, x)) / 2)
        rate = 100 * (mid - close) / close
        array.set(sr_labels, x + 1, label.new(x=bar_index + labelloc, y=mid, text=str.tostring(mid) + '(' + str.tostring(rate, '#.##') + '%)', color=mid >= close ? color.red : color.lime, textcolor=mid >= close ? color.white : color.black, style=mid >= close ? label.style_label_down : label.style_label_up))

        array.set(sr_lines, x + 1, line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=mid, x2=bar_index - 1, y2=mid, extend=extend.both, color=mid >= close ? resistancecolor : supportcolor, style=Lstyle, width=linewidth))
```

At the end of this code I have an array that controls the output. How can I add a input.bool as to be able to switch the indicator on and off ( turn the ouput on or off ), I do not see anywhere within the plotting function that would allow me to do so. The specific array controlling the output is the last array.

Answer (score 0):

you should just set all the color = X lines to color.rgb() and set the opacity to an integer so u can change the input from X to 100 disable it like this:

```
opacityred = input.int(title="opacityred", defval=94)
opacitylime = input.int(title="opacitylime", defval=94)
var int opr = opacityred
var int opl = opacitylime
resistancecolor = color.rgb(235, 63, 63,opr)
supportcolor = color.rgb(77, 211, 146,opl)
```

heres the fully finished script:

```
//@version=5
indicator("SR", overlay=true)

prd = int(10)
ppsrc = string('High/Low')
maxnumpp = int(20)
ChannelW = int(10)
maxnumsr = int(5)
min_strength = int(2)
labelloc = int(20)
linestyle = string('Dashed')
linewidth = int(2)

showpp = (false)
tplevels = input.bool(false, "Automatic S/R Levels")
opacityred = input.int(title="opacityred", defval=94)
opacitylime = input.int(title="opacitylime", defval=94)
var int opr = opacityred
var int opl = opacitylime
resistancecolor = color.rgb(235, 63, 63,opr)
supportcolor = color.rgb(77, 211, 146,opl)

float src1 = ppsrc == 'High/Low' ? high : math.max(close, open)
float src2 = ppsrc == 'High/Low' ? low : math.min(close, open)
float ph = ta.pivothigh(src1, prd, prd)
float pl = ta.pivotlow(src2, prd, prd)


Lstyle = linestyle == 'Dashed' ? line.style_solid : linestyle == 'Solid' ? line.style_solid : line.style_solid

//calculate maximum S/R channel zone width
prdhighest = ta.highest(300)
prdlowest = ta.lowest(300)
cwidth = (prdhighest - prdlowest) * ChannelW / 100

var pivotvals = array.new_float(0)

if ph or pl
    array.unshift(pivotvals, ph ? ph : pl)
    if array.size(pivotvals) > maxnumpp  // limit the array size
        array.pop(pivotvals)

get_sr_vals(ind) =>
    float lo = array.get(pivotvals, ind)
    float hi = lo
    int numpp = 0
    for y = 0 to array.size(pivotvals) - 1 by 1
        float cpp = array.get(pivotvals, y)
        float wdth = cpp <= lo ? hi - cpp : cpp - lo
        if wdth <= cwidth  // fits the max channel width?
            if cpp <= hi
                lo := math.min(lo, cpp)
            else
                hi := math.max(hi, cpp)

            numpp += 1
            numpp
    [hi, lo, numpp]

var sr_up_level = array.new_float(0)
var sr_dn_level = array.new_float(0)
sr_strength = array.new_float(0)

find_loc(strength) =>
    ret = array.size(sr_strength)
    for i = ret > 0 ? array.size(sr_strength) - 1 : na to 0 by 1
        if strength <= array.get(sr_strength, i)
            break
        ret := i
        ret
    ret

check_sr(hi, lo, strength) =>
    ret = true
    for i = 0 to array.size(sr_up_level) > 0 ? array.size(sr_up_level) - 1 : na by 1
        //included?
        if array.get(sr_up_level, i) >= lo and array.get(sr_up_level, i) <= hi or array.get(sr_dn_level, i) >= lo and array.get(sr_dn_level, i) <= hi
            if strength >= array.get(sr_strength, i)
                array.remove(sr_strength, i)
                array.remove(sr_up_level, i)
                array.remove(sr_dn_level, i)
                ret
            else
                ret := false
                ret
            break
    ret

var sr_lines = array.new_line(11, na)
var sr_labels = array.new_label(11, na)

for x = 1 to 10 by 1
    rate = 100 * (label.get_y(array.get(sr_labels, x)) - close) / close
    label.set_text(array.get(sr_labels, x), text=str.tostring(label.get_y(array.get(sr_labels, x))) + '(' + str.tostring(rate, '#.##') + '%)')
    label.set_x(array.get(sr_labels, x), x=bar_index + labelloc)
    label.set_color(array.get(sr_labels, x), color=label.get_y(array.get(sr_labels, x)) >= close ? color.rgb(207, 30, 30, opr) : color.rgb(84, 175, 131, opr))
    label.set_textcolor(array.get(sr_labels, x), textcolor=label.get_y(array.get(sr_labels, x)) >= close ? color.rgb(235, 229, 229,opr) : color.rgb(30, 34, 43,opr))
    label.set_style(array.get(sr_labels, x), style=label.get_y(array.get(sr_labels, x)) >= close ? label.style_label_down : label.style_label_up)
    line.set_color(array.get(sr_lines, x), color=line.get_y1(array.get(sr_lines, x)) >= close ? color.rgb(207, 30, 30, opr) : color.rgb(84, 175, 131, opr))

if ph or pl
    //because of new calculation, remove old S/R levels
    array.clear(sr_up_level)
    array.clear(sr_dn_level)
    array.clear(sr_strength)
    //find S/R zones
    for x = 0 to array.size(pivotvals) - 1 by 1
        [hi, lo, strength] = get_sr_vals(x)
        if check_sr(hi, lo, strength)
            loc = find_loc(strength)
            // if strength is in first maxnumsr sr then insert it to the arrays 
            if loc < maxnumsr and strength >= min_strength
                array.insert(sr_strength, loc, strength)
                array.insert(sr_up_level, loc, hi)
                array.insert(sr_dn_level, loc, lo)
                // keep size of the arrays = 5
                if array.size(sr_strength) > maxnumsr
                    array.pop(sr_strength)
                    array.pop(sr_up_level)
                    array.pop(sr_dn_level)

    for x = 1 to 10 by 1
        line.delete(array.get(sr_lines, x))
        label.delete(array.get(sr_labels, x))

    for x = 0 to array.size(sr_up_level) > 0 ? array.size(sr_up_level) - 1 : na by 1
        float mid = math.round_to_mintick((array.get(sr_up_level, x) + array.get(sr_dn_level, x)) / 2)
        rate = 100 * (mid - close) / close
        array.set(sr_labels, x + 1, label.new(x=bar_index + labelloc, y=mid, text=str.tostring(mid) + '(' + str.tostring(rate, '#.##') + '%)', color=mid >= close ? color.rgb(250, 89, 89,opr) : color.rgb(25, 231, 132), textcolor=mid >= close ? color.rgb(247, 230, 230,opr) : color.rgb(63, 67, 80,opr), style=mid >= close ? label.style_label_down : label.style_label_up))

        array.set(sr_lines, x + 1, line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=mid, x2=bar_index - 1, y2=mid, extend=extend.both, color=mid >= close ? resistancecolor : supportcolor, style=Lstyle, width=linewidth))
```

ultimately u could try something like this :

```
 //@version=5
indicator("Smart Money", overlay=true)

// Inputs
prd = input.int(10)
ppsrc = input.string('High/Low')
maxnumpp = input.int(20)
ChannelW = input.int(10)
maxnumsr = input.int(5)
min_strength = input.int(2)
labelloc = input.int(20)
linestyle = input.string('Dashed')
linewidth = input.int(2)
resistancecolor = input.color(color.red, "Resistance line color")
supportcolor = input.color(color.lime, "Support line color")
showpp = input.bool(false, "Show Pivot Points")
tplevels = input.bool(false, "Automatic S/R Levels")
show_indicator = input.bool(true, title="Show Indicator")
show_indicator1 = input.bool(true, title="Show Indicator1")
show_indicator2 = input.bool(true, title="Show Indicator2")
show_indicator3 = input.bool(true, title="Show Indicator3")

// Pivot Points
float src1 = ppsrc == 'High/Low' ? high : math.max(close, open)
float src2 = ppsrc == 'High/Low' ? low : math.min(close, open)
float ph = ta.pivothigh(src1, prd, prd)
float pl = ta.pivotlow(src2, prd, prd)

// Style
Lstyle = linestyle == 'Dashed' ? line.style_solid : linestyle == 'Solid' ? line.style_solid : line.style_solid

//calculate maximum S/R channel zone width
prdhighest = ta.highest(300)
prdlowest = ta.lowest(300)
cwidth = (prdhighest - prdlowest) * ChannelW / 100

var pivotvals = array.new_float(0)

if ph or pl
    array.unshift(pivotvals, ph ? ph : pl)
    if array.size(pivotvals) > maxnumpp  // limit the array size
        array.pop(pivotvals)

get_sr_vals(ind) =>
    float lo = array.get(pivotvals, ind)
    float hi = lo
    int numpp = 0
    for y = 0 to array.size(pivotvals) - 1 by 1
        float cpp = array.get(pivotvals, y)
        float wdth = cpp <= lo ? hi - cpp : cpp - lo
        if wdth <= cwidth  // fits the max channel width?
            if cpp <= hi
                lo := math.min(lo, cpp)
            else
                hi := math.max(hi, cpp)

            numpp += 1
    [hi, lo, numpp]

var sr_up_level = array.new_float(0)
var sr_dn_level = array.new_float(0)
sr_strength = array.new_float(0)

find_loc(strength) =>
    ret = array.size(sr_strength)
    for i = ret > 0 ? array.size(sr_strength) - 1 : na to 0 by 1
        if strength <= array.get(sr_strength, i)
            break
        ret := i
        ret
    ret

check_sr(hi, lo, strength) =>
    ret = true
    for i = 0 to array.size(sr_up_level) > 0 ? array.size(sr_up_level) - 1 : na by 1
        //included?
        if array.get(sr_up_level, i) >= lo and array.get(sr_up_level, i) <= hi or array.get(sr_dn_level, i) >= lo and array.get(sr_dn_level, i) <= hi
            if strength >= array.get(sr_strength, i)
                array.remove(sr_strength, i)
                array.remove(sr_up_level, i)
                array.remove(sr_dn_level, i)
                ret
            else
                ret := false
                ret
            break
    ret

var sr_lines = array.new_line(11, na)
var sr_labels = array.new_label(11, na)

for x = 1 to 10 by 1
    if show_indicator2
        rate = 100 * (label.get_y(array.get(sr_labels, x)) - close) / close
        label.set_text(array.get(sr_labels, x), text=str.tostring(label.get_y(array.get(sr_labels, x))) + '(' + str.tostring(rate, '#.##') + '%)')
        label.set_x(array.get(sr_labels, x), x=bar_index + labelloc)
        label.set_color(array.get(sr_labels, x), color=label.get_y(array.get(sr_labels, x)) >= close ? color.red : color.lime)
        label.set_textcolor(array.get(sr_labels, x), textcolor=label.get_y(array.get(sr_labels, x)) >= close ? color.white : color.black)
        label.set_style(array.get(sr_labels, x), style=label.get_y(array.get(sr_labels, x)) >= close ? label.style_label_down : label.style_label_up)
        line.set_color(array.get(sr_lines, x), color=line.get_y1(array.get(sr_lines, x)) >= close ? resistancecolor : supportcolor)
    else 
        if x <= array.size(sr_lines)
            line.delete(array.get(sr_lines, x))
 
        if x <= array.size(sr_labels)
            label.delete(array.get(sr_labels, x))
if ph or pl
    //because of new calculation, remove old S/R levels
    array.clear(sr_up_level)
    array.clear(sr_dn_level)
    array.clear(sr_strength)
    //find S/R zones
    for x = 0 to array.size(pivotvals) - 1 by 1
        [hi, lo, strength] = get_sr_vals(x)
        if check_sr(hi, lo, strength)
            loc = find_loc(strength)
            // if strength is in first maxnumsr sr then insert it to the arrays 
            if loc < maxnumsr and strength >= min_strength and show_indicator3
                array.insert(sr_strength, loc, strength)
                array.insert(sr_up_level, loc, hi)
                array.insert(sr_dn_level, loc, lo)
                // keep size of the arrays = 5
                if array.size(sr_strength) > maxnumsr
                    array.pop(sr_strength)
                    array.pop(sr_up_level)
                    array.pop(sr_dn_level)
                

for x = 1 to 10 by 1
    if tplevels and show_indicator1
        rate = 100 * (label.get_y(array.get(sr_labels, x)) - close) / close
        label.set_text(array.get(sr_labels, x), text=str.tostring(label.get_y(array.get(sr_labels, x))) + '(' + str.tostring(rate, '#.##') + '%)')
        label.set_x(array.get(sr_labels, x), x=bar_index + labelloc)
        label.set_color(array.get(sr_labels, x), color=label.get_y(array.get(sr_labels, x)) >= close ? color.red : color.lime)
        label.set_textcolor(array.get(sr_labels, x), textcolor=label.get_y(array.get(sr_labels, x)) >= close ? color.white : color.black)
        label.set_style(array.get(sr_labels, x), style=label.get_y(array.get(sr_labels, x)) >= close ? label.style_label_down : label.style_label_up)
        line.set_color(array.get(sr_lines, x), color=line.get_y1(array.get(sr_lines, x)) >= close ? resistancecolor : supportcolor)
    else
        line.delete(array.get(sr_lines, x))
        label.delete(array.get(sr_labels, x))
if ph or pl and show_indicator 
    //because of new calculation, remove old S/R levels
    array.clear(sr_up_level)
    array.clear(sr_dn_level)
    array.clear(sr_strength)
    //find S/R zones
    for x = 0 to array.size(pivotvals) - 1 by 1
        [hi, lo, strength] = get_sr_vals(x)
        if check_sr(hi, lo, strength)
            loc = find_loc(strength)
            // if strength is in first maxnumsr sr then insert it to the arrays 
            if loc < maxnumsr and strength >= min_strength
                array.insert(sr_strength, loc, strength)
                array.insert(sr_up_level, loc, hi)
                array.insert(sr_dn_level, loc, lo)
                // keep size of the arrays = 5
                if array.size(sr_strength) > maxnumsr
                    array.pop(sr_strength)
                    array.pop(sr_up_level)
                    array.pop(sr_dn_level)
else
    for x = 1 to 10 by 1
        line.delete(array.get(sr_lines, x))
        label.delete(array.get(sr_labels, x))

    for x = 0 to array.size(sr_up_level) > 0 ? array.size(sr_up_level) - 1 : na by 1
        float mid = math.round_to_mintick((array.get(sr_up_level, x) + array.get(sr_dn_level, x)) / 2)
        rate = 100 * (mid - close) / close
        array.set(sr_labels, x + 1, label.new(x=bar_index + labelloc, y=mid, text=str.tostring(mid) + '(' + str.tostring(rate, '#.##') + '%)', color=mid >= close ? color.red : color.lime, textcolor=mid >= close ? color.white : color.black, style=mid >= close ? label.style_label_down : label.style_label_up))

        array.set(sr_lines, x + 1, line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=mid, x2=bar_index - 1, y2=mid, extend=extend.both, color=mid >= close ? resistancecolor : supportcolor, style=Lstyle, width=linewidth))
```